# how to refresh cache for custom module only?

Tags: magento-enterprise, cache

I'm trying to update cache for a custom module only (config.xml to be specific)
Is this possible? The situation is this that we can't refresh cache as it is live server and it'd affect the whole site.
so need a quick solution to only refresh the particular cache separately.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For clean particular cache just pass type in this code :

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($type);
```

Possible types are as follows:

1. config
2. layout
3. block_html
4. translate
5. collections
6. eav
7. config_api
8. config_api2

And these can be returned by calling `Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->getTypes()`

Comment: so it's not possible to refresh cache for a particular module only? Is it because the config.xml of all modules get merged?

Comment: @RT no its not posible to refresh a module cache only.